# Metrics for Evaluating Performance of Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model

I built a Logistic Regression model and I would like to evaluate the performance of the model. I would like to understand its evaluation metrics.

What do the metrics Sensitivity, Specificity, False Positives Rate, Precision, Recall, and Accuracy tell us about this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Logistic regression is not same as Linear regression , predicting just accuracy will mislead. 
** Confusion Matrix** is one way to evaluate the performance of your model. Checking the values of `True Positives`, `False Negatives ( Type II Error)` are really important.

** ROC Curve** Receiver Operating Characteristic(ROC) summarizes the model’s performance by evaluating the trade offs between true positive rate (sensitivity) and false positive rate(1- specificity)

The below link will give you more information:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/beginners-guide-on-logistic-regression-in-r/